# WP8 Uploading/Downloading large files

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am fairly new to Windows Phone development. We have a scenario where we allow user to upload or download files but along with authentication (oAuth, NTLM, forms all standard mechanism but not limited to oAuth).

Now so far our RnD suggest that we have following options

**1- Resource Intensive Agent**
The [constraints associated with Resource Intensive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforResourceintensiveAgents) (like Minimum battery etc.) have lead us to drop this option

**2- Periodic Agent**
A relatively better option, however as they run after 30 minutes and the constraint of 10 minutes duration gives us doubt that on mobile if user wants to upload a video of say 1-2 GB, it does not guarantee competition and u can anticipate other problems associated with this approach.

**3- Background File Transfer**
This is the best option in our scenario however my colleague told me that it does not support basic windows authentication and that we cannot change user-agent etc.

**4- On Application**
Another option is to perform network operation on application but we cant retain user on application for longer duration and also after sometime lock screen would appear. So...

Can anyone who have experienced similar scenario or from product team can guide here. It's a common scenario, are we missing something here? or is it really API limitation?

Answer (score 1):

**Resource Intensive Agents** will indeed not work for your use case because they require external power to work. Not to mention that if the user receives a phone call the agent terminates.

**Periodic Agent** Have a **25 second** limited duration, not 10 minutes (10 minutes are in resource intensive agents), so they are really no an option if you need to upload a gigabyte of information.

**Background File Transfers** have a hard limit of 100 megabytes. (It's even less on cellular internet).

**On Application** is a very possible option, you can prevent the phone from going to lock screen if that's a problem. The bigger issue here is that the user is pretty much stuck for the duration of the upload. More importantly, this seems to be your *only* option out of the four you mentioned.

Comment: Is background transfer really limited to oAuth? 
And yes on application is not good in user experience... How can we prevent lock screen from appearing, any refer?

Comment: The problem with background file transfer is first and foremost the file size. As for preventing the lock screen that's also pretty bad UX to be honest.. As for preventing the lock screen - here you go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: By the way - I'm in Finland right now in a Microsoft/Nokia hosted windows phone workshop. I don't mind asking their tech guru, but I doubt he'll have a different answer.

Comment: Yeah please ask... I kind of wondering about why they have designed APIs this way... the current solution is not good in terms of UX

Comment: I doubt a lot about the Background File Transfer not supporting authentication. It's basic request where you can set your headers so I don't right away see any problem of using authentication with it.

I will write a sample and post it here when done

Comment: @AdilMughal Teemu is the one I was referring to.

Comment: Can't find any service that would take plain GET/POST most need multi-part which is whole own story. Here's example how LiveSDK handles this situation: https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/tree/master/src/WP8/Source/Internal

Comment: @TeemuTapanila I am not sure but can we NTLM/Windows authentication with Background file transfer? Any reference?

Comment: @AdilMughal I'm not familiar enough with NTLM/Windows authentication. But if I understood correctly from MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789031.aspx) and few other sources. After you have completed the authentication you should be able to use that authentication on Background Transfer. Didn't find any samples how to do it.